# sudo apt update error on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, repository

Here is what it looks like:

```
sudo apt update                                  
Err:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::19 80]
Reading package lists... Done                 
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Are you actually running 22.04? because `impish` is ubuntu 21.10, which is now EOL (as of July 14) and therefore can't be updated

Comment: Following on from @Esther's comment, if you are actually running 22.04, your sources list is messed up.

Comment: A gentle reminder: please remember to be nice to the New contributors: https://askubuntu.com/conduct

Comment: I guess I may have added **impish** accidently while trying to install some 3rd party apps. Now, this is how I solved it: `mkdir ~/.apt-backup` `mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list* ~/.apt-backup` Don't forget to add sudo.